# Data backup in recovery mode?

Tags: samsung, backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery, android-13

My Samsung a51 is broken and for some reason I can't turn it on, download mode is not available, only recovery mode. It has quite a lot of important data, mostly pictures. Is there a way to make a backup in recovery mode?

Comment: No... Everything in Android is encrypted... even if you could get to the files, they would be unusable.